# Java Scanner Class Help

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I would like to find out how to print a a certain string from an input file using a scanner. For the string to be printed the line must start with *star and the string must be surrounded by quotation marks, and be the next token and on the same line as *star ignoring white space of course.

Sample input text file: "test.txt"

> this is a test
>
> *star "variableX"
>
> more testing
>
> *star "variableY
>
> much more
>
> testing
>
> *star next"variableZ"

Based on this sample input text the output should be only.

> "variableX"

Here is part of my code:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File ("test.txt"));

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

        if(scanner.hasNext("*star")) {
            scanner.next();

            if(scanner.hasNext()){
                String test = scanner.next();
                System.out.println(test);
            }
```

But it's missing some key things. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){

        String line = scanner.nextLine();

        if(line.startsWith("*star")){

        String[] split= line.split("\\s+"); //Split the string where there is whitespace

        //No whitespace after *star 
        if ((split.length<2)){
        System.exit(0); 
        }

        String file= split[1];
        String star=split[0];

        String file1=file.trim(); //Removes whitespace 

        if(file1.startsWith("\"")&&(file1.endsWith("\""))){

        System.out.println(file1);
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package so3947761;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
  private static final Pattern RELEVANT_LINE_PATTERN =
      Pattern.compile("^\\*star\\s+\"(.*)\"$");

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = scanner.nextLine();

      Matcher m = RELEVANT_LINE_PATTERN.matcher(line);
      if (m.matches()) {
        String data = m.group(1);

        System.out.println(data);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Some remarks:

- I'm using the Scanner only for splitting the input into lines.
- The real work is done by the regular expression pattern, which contains all the requirements that you stated.
- If you want to parse the text in quotes further (for example to replace `\n` with a newline), this cannot be done by the regular expression, so you have to explicitly define which sequences to replace.
- You may want to add `\\s*` at the right of the `^` (beginning of the line) and at the left of the `$` (end of the line) if you want to allow whitespace at these places.

Comment: That regex seem to be good but did not work for me for the input given in the question

Comment: That's weird because I tested it with exactly the input you gave. Well, almost, I removed the leading white-space. So you should probably follow the advice in the fourth bullet point above.

Answer (score -1):

This does the trick

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File ("c:\\test.txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            if(scanner.hasNext(Pattern.compile("\\*star"))) {
                scanner.next();
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
                return;
            }
            else
                scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
The quotation part was missing in the answer, did not remember to put it as I got the output even without it, but here it is a more robust solution:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner (new File ("c:\\new.txt"));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            if(scanner.hasNext(Pattern.compile("\\*star"))) {
                scanner.next();
                String s = scanner.nextLine();
                Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\".+\"").matcher(s);
                if(m.find())
                {
                    System.out.println(m.group());
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
                scanner.nextLine();
        }
```

Comment: This one fails to strip the leading *star and "" quotes, as in the example output...

Comment: did you really try to run it on the input? It sure got the right answer for me even without the quotation code I have just added; but I agree it should have been there. The previous code sure stripped of the leading *star(when a line started with it, as mentioned) and quotations need not be stripped, as shown in the output.